# What's the best collection for Datetime objects with fast access to specific date

Tags: c#, datetime

I have to store objects in a collection that contain a Datetime object as Key.  The collection does include all dates of a year. 
I need to be able to fast access random objects by date,  but also to be able to access the next,  previous day,  one week/month before/after of a specific  date.

My first thought was to use a Dictionary and always access the desired object through the Index. 
Is this the best approach for this?

Comment: if the collection includes (just) all dates of a year, an array containing 365/366 elements would be enough. The index is then simply the day of the year.

Comment: But if I want to jump one month forward/backwards it starts to be more difficult. DateTime offers Month and Year adding with handling of different lengths of months and leap years. I think a combination of a liked list together with a Directory pointing to the list nodes could be the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();

DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
ht.Add(d1, "Today");
```

but remember that Dictionary is a generic type, Hashtable is not. so you need to decide what best for you.

Comment: What would be the Advantage of HashTable over Dictionary? Internal Dictionary also works with hashing, doesn't it?

Comment: The main advantage is the speed of access while searching.

Comment: So Hashtable is really faster than Dictionary, didn't know that. Thanks

Comment: I done some research and the hashtable not always the best case: you can see the results : http://blog.bodurov.com/Performance-SortedList-SortedDictionary-Dictionary-Hashtable/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your research. So I think for my project Dictionry with combination of List where every Entry also stores the ListIndex is the best combination.

Comment: great, glad to help.